# Is it bad practice to have a DB access in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:?

Tags: ios, database

We had a crash come in, luckily from on in-house user, so we were able to examine her phone in detail, and reconstructed what happened: She has a really old and slow iPhone.  When she upgraded to our newest version, the first time there was a DB access it triggered a migration, which on her old slow phone apparently took a really long time.  Unfortunately, the first time we ping the database is in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, and iOS decided that our app was taking too long to finish, and killed the app -- in the middle of a DB migrate.  Which meant every time she tried to launch the app after that, the DB was corrupted and bad things happened.

Obviously, we can get around this by not doing any DB accesses in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.  But on the other hand, we've seen this exactly once ever, on a user with an old phone (and, presumably, a really full database).  So I'm not sure how pants-wetting this "bug" is...

Is it considered terrible practice to hit the DB in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, and we should fix this at the next possible opportunity?  Or is it not that big of a deal, and we just had a "perfect storm" here?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, you should not perform a long-running task in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions cause it musts return as soon as possible. I don't know what is the limit. But in your case, you've reached the limit.

So the solution is to add a Splash Screen (or waiting screen) while you have to perform a long-running task (big db migration for example). Put the migration in this ViewController (not in AppDelegate) then you won't have problems even in slow device.

Comment: We already have a splash screen for the stuff we expect to be time-consuming.  The code in question is normally just a very quick database query (looking up a profile name or something IIRC), it was just in this weird case that it ended up taking long enough to get us shut down.  That's what made me think maybe it is just generally bad practice to ever touch the database in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, because you can never be sure how long a db query can take.  I'm not hearing an overwhelming "Yes that is horrible never do that!", so I'm inclined to back-burner this for now..